# Github page does not show up

Tags: github

I have a public repo

```
  https://github.com/coolshare/ReactReduxStarterKit
```

and I have enabled my github page

```
 Your site is published at https://coolshare.github.io/ReactReduxStarterKit/

GitHub Pages is designed to host your personal, organization, or project pages from a GitHub repository.

Source

Your GitHub Pages site is currently being built from the master branch. Learn more.

Theme chooser

Select a theme to build your site with a Jekyll theme. Learn more.

Your site is currently using the Cayman theme.
```

When I tried

https://coolshare.github.io/ReactReduxStarterKit/

and got "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - https://coolshare.github.io/bundle.js"

and the browser has load the src as

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>React-Redux Starter Kit</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='root'>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It seems that it was looking for a bundle.js at my doc root

```
      coolshare.github.io/
```

but it resides at

```
        coolshare.github.io/ReactReduxStarterKit/
```

How can I fix it?

thanks

Comment: When did you setup that page? If you did just moments ago, then maybe give it a few hours at least.

Comment: try removing `/` or add `./` in `src`.. `src="bundle.js"` or `src="./bundle.js"`

Comment: Yes! that made it. But I need to have a set of routing for github